# Using a link to a crontab file located elsewhere than /etc/crontab (Debian)

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, cron, symbolic-link, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance in AWS. As you know, if my instance crashes I lose all data located in the local EC2 hard drive. Of course I have an EBS for my data, but `/etc` is located in the non-permanent-local-drive, and I am trying to move all system config files to the EBS.

For the crontab, my Debian reads the `/etc/crontab`. I tried to symlink the file and it did not work. Do you known why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider switching from an ephemeral instance (where the root file system goes away when the instance shuts off) to an EBS backed instance (where the entire root file system is on an EBS drive). This will solve your worry and save you from hacking the OS.

You might find tutorials such as [this one](http://webkist.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/creating-an-amazon-ec2-ebs-ami-from-a-running-instance/) helpful.